# Changing the ID value based on another column

Tags: r

I have a large data set that looks something like this:

```
Conv.  Rev.  ID  Order  path_no
 0     0     1    1        1
 1     50    1    2        1
 0     0     1    3        2
 1     100   1    4        2
 0     0     2    1        1
 0     0     2    2        1
 1     150   2    3        1
 1     100   2    4        2
```

I want to make a new ID column based on when there is a new path_no, then the ID will change. So I am hoping it will look something like this:

```
Conv.  Rev.  ID  Order  path_no
  0     0     1    1        1
  1     50    1    2        1
  0     0     2    3        2
  1     100   2    4        2
  0     0     3    1        1
  0     0     3    2        1
  1     150   3    3        1
  1     100   4    4        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `rleid` from `data.table` should do the trick. Here's one solution that uses `data.table` and `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, ID = data.table::rleid(path_no))

  Conv. Rev. ID Order path_no
1     0    0  1     1       1
2     1   50  1     2       1
3     0    0  2     3       2
4     1  100  2     4       2
5     0    0  3     1       1
6     0    0  3     2       1
7     1  150  3     3       1
8     1  100  4     4       2
```

Or with `data.table` only:

```
dt <- setDT(df)
dt[, ID := rleid(path_no)][]

   Conv. Rev. ID Order path_no
1:     0    0  1     1       1
2:     1   50  1     2       1
3:     0    0  2     3       2
4:     1  100  2     4       2
5:     0    0  3     1       1
6:     0    0  3     2       1
7:     1  150  3     3       1
8:     1  100  4     4       2
```

Data:

```
text <- "Conv.  Rev.  ID  Order  path_no
        0     0     1    1        1
        1     50    1    2        1
        0     0     1    3        2
        1     100   1    4        2
        0     0     2    1        1
        0     0     2    2        1
        1     150   2    3        1
        1     100   2    4        2"

df <- read.table(text = text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can go for a simple for loop:

```
vals <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)
nobs <- length(vals)
idx <- rep(1, nobs)
for (i in 2:nobs) {
   if (vals[i] != vals[i-1]) {
       idx[i] <- idx[i-1] + 1
   } else {
       idx[i] <- idx[i-1]
   }
 }
```